# Hide UIAlertView programmatically?

Tags: iphone, uialertview

Is there a way to hide UIAlertView programmatically? Actually I have added a UITextField in UIAlertView and I want to perform the same operation as on "Ok" button press when a user hits the keyboard return key.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Call

```
[theAlertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
```

when you handle the return key.

Comment: Thanks for this. If you want it a little more flexible you could also say `[theAlertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex: theAlertView.cancelButtonIndex animated:YES];` or `[theAlertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex: theAlertView.firstOtherButtonIndex animated:YES];` to click the first not cancel button.