# How to dismiss a phonegap notification programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cordova

Is there any way to programmatically dismiss navigator.notification.alert()?  I alert when there's a location services error, but if it clears, I'd prefer to dismiss it rather than require the user to do it manually.

Any ideas or solutions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't programmatically dismiss an `alert()` dialog, no.

What you could do, however, is instead of using `alert()` implement your own custom overlay that looks/acts similarly to an alert, and then you can easily dismiss that whenever you want.  Some additional discussion is here:

[Javascript close alert box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463368/javascript-close-alert-box)

**Edit**

I did a [bit more investigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251557/phonegap-and-prompt) into this and I no longer believe that the Phonegap `alert()` dialog is actually the same as the native JavaScript dialog.  They are using some clever tricks to call back into native code (on both Android and iOS) to show the alert.

As such, it *may* be possible to dismiss the dialog programmatically, but almost certainly not from directly within your JavaScript code.  You would need to use some similar trickery to call back from your JavaScript into native code, and then locate and dismiss the Phonegap alert view.  The first part may be fairly difficult.  The second part is trivial:

[Hide UIAlertView programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853887/hide-uialertview-programatically)

Answer (score 2):

Hey i have got a change in java file for this.
src/android/Notification.java

Added a reference to dlg.create()

First Declare this..

```
private AlertDialog alertbox;
```

Then add a case where you send "dismiss"  from javascript

```
else if (action.equals("dismiss")) {
     this.dismissAll();
}
```

Method to be added :

```
public void dismissAll(){
    alertbox.dismiss();
}
```

Do remember to add the same in notification.js in www folder of notification plugin

```
dismiss: function(message, completeCallback, title, buttonLabel) {
    var _title = (title || "Alert");//Doesnt Matter!
    var _buttonLabel = (buttonLabel || "OK");//Doesnt Matter!
    exec(completeCallback, null, "Notification", "dismiss", [message, _title, _buttonLabel]);
},
```

Now add

```
alertbox = dlg.create();
alertbox.show();
```

instead of

```
dlg.create();
dlg.show();
```

at all the places.

And you are good to go by calling

```
navigator.notification.dismiss("",null,"");
```

This will dismiss all the alerts / confirm / prompt opened.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps create a dialog out of a div or some other element and display that to the user so you can dismiss it easily.

JavaScript

```
function geo_error() {
    //only append error message if none exists
    if ($('#page_container').find('.geo_error').length == 0) {
        $('#page_container').append('<div class="geo_error">A Geolocation Error Has Occured</div>');
    }
}
function get_success(position) {
    //hide the error message on success
    $('#page_container').find('.geo_error').hide();
}
```

CSS

```
.geo_error {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```